# How to check coolant leak in a Jetta

Tags: vw, jetta, coolant-leak

My 2008 2.5L Jetta(in the US) has a coolant leak as I filled the tank to max line a couple of times but it slowly(over hours) went down to the same level in the picture. I don't see any leak on the ground below the car and the engine oil seemed normal.

Volkswagen engine bays aren't the most visible but I still tried seeing around with a flashlight, but didn't get anywhere.

What else can I check?

[image: coolant reservoir tank]

Comment: Does your car have a cover or panel _below_ the engine (my 2019 Jetta does) ? If so, there might be drips pooling on top of the cover, which don't run out onto the ground until the car moves.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Yeah, there is a cover below the engine as well as above.